# Java: Subclass constructor with inherited arguments

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, arguments

I have an abstract base class for 3 concrete classes.
Suppose the base class' constructor takes 2 arguments. The constructor of each subclass takes those 2 arguments plus an additional argument or two, and passes the 2 necessary arguments to superclass constructor. Something like:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    public long field1;
    private SomeType field2;

    public SuperClass(long field1, SomeType field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
    ...
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private String sometext;

    public SubClass(long field1, SomeType field2, String sometext) {
        super(field1, field2);
        this.sometext = sometext;
    }
    ...
}
```

I suppose this isn't too bad. However, if sometime down the road I decide I need to change the constructor of `SuperClass` (say for example it needs an additional argument for a new field), I don't want to have to edit the subclasses as well.

So I'm looking for an elegant way to tell the `SubClass` constructor to "take the arguments `super()` needs and pass them to it, also take `String sometext` and do something with it". So in pseudo-code:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private String sometext;

    public SubClass(paramlist:super(), String sometext) {
        super(paramlist:super());
        this.sometext = sometext;
    }
    ...
}
```

That way I could just change the `SuperClass` definition and the code that instantiates `SubClass` and not worry about `SubClass` itself.

I've looked at possible solutions like using dedicated objects to bundle the arguments together, using Builders or even making `SuperClass` concrete and passing instances of it to `SubClass` constructors and then tediously copying the fields. I don't think any of these solutions is right for me, because every one of them *adds* complexity to my code instead of reducing it.

Is there a relavitely simple way to do this, similar in complexity to the pseudo-code listed above? Am I possibly missing a super-obvious fact that prevents this from being a thing?

Comment: There is no real way to accomplish exactly what you want. My advice is get a great IDE and it will do the work for you. When you refactor a signature in most IDEs that are mainstream, Eclispe and Intellij they will also edit the subclass if you use the right features in the program. That oy as you said roll your own solution by bundling args into an array or a wrapper class.

Comment: I think you list your best alternatives: Bundling all arguments to the super constructor in a separate class, or skipping ordinary constructors and going with a builder instead.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Yes, I could definitely use IDE functionality for that. Thank you for reminding me - as you can see I'm still a noob in Java ;) I kind of figured that there probably isn't such a language construct, but I posted anyway, to see if maybe there actually is a way to do it or if someone can explain why there isn't. Anyway, thanks for a quick reply!

Comment: You can use a composition instead of an inheritance, see this article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html

Comment: That is another possible way to tackle it. Thank you for bringing it up. However, I'm afraid that it would add the most complexity to my code (out of the aforementioned solutions), since my classes inherit from each other on a _"is a"_ basis and I use references to `SuperClass` to simplify operations on all kinds of `SubClass` objects and make collections universal.